# Use php while running mod_wsgi-express with django

Tags: php, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am currently running a django application on my server and everything is fine with it but when I try to access php files like phpliteadmin.php which is located in /etc/mod_wsgi-express-80/htdocs I can only see the code but the php is not executed. I could find similar questions but nothing really helpful. I just started web developing so I need some help.

Some say I should change the `<VirtualHost *:80>` part but there are multiple of it and my /etc/mod_wsgi-express-80/httpd.conf looks different to theirs, I assume it's because they are not using the "express" version.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to show us the relevant parts from the apache configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Apache installation has PHP installed, if using `mod_wsgi-express`, simply provide the `--with-php5` option.

I don't track PHP versions and that option was added just to show could be done. If there are newer PHP versions then `mod_wsgi-express` would need to be updated to know about them. If there are going to be multiple PHP versions, then perhaps needs to be generalised to `--with-php` with a separate `--php-version` option or have it auto detect which PHP version is installed.

You are best off jumping on the mod_wsgi mailing list to discuss changes.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/finding-help.html

Comment: I will try using the --with-php5 option. I am using PHP 5.4.45 .

Comment: It works fine now, but I also had to copy phplib5.so from apache/modules to my virtualenv. Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't have needed to do that. What was the error you were getting which made you think you needed to?

Comment: It said phplib5.so is missing... Anyway I terminated the server later on so I can not recreate the error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like this in your virtualhost configuration

```
#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

This will tell apache to run php interpreter for php files.

Comment: Because they are using ``mod_wsgi-express`` the complete Apache configuration is generated for them. To simply slot in additional configuraton they will need to add it to a separate file and use the ``--include-file`` option to ``mod_wsgi-express``. This will add it at the end of the Apache configuration. They will though also need to add a ``LoadModule`` line at the start of that file to load the PHP module itself.